# How can i fetch timezone code in react.js?

Tags: reactjs

I have a small problem with my code 'Weather app' when I am choosing a city I get the wrong local time but after that, I choose the same city and I get the correct local time

project link : [enter link description here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/44hsh37w0yxzmt5/weather-arabic2.zip?dl=0)

[image]
[image]

Comment: can you provide a code example of things you've done so far?

Comment: Please show how you get the time

Comment: https://momentjs.com/timezone/?

Comment: Please include the code you are working with.

Comment: React is a UI library, it cannot give you timezones. Also, JS can only give you your local timezone. if you want code that defers timezone from a string, either use Google API for location or monent.timezone or some other library

Comment: it is not give a correct time in the first time but when i click 'Get Weather' button again it is give me the correct time for any city